Batch Job doesn't work via schedulable and errors out with " [REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped."
I have a question related to scheduled jobs in fullcopy sandbox. My scheduled batch job triggers another batch from finish method and this continues till 4th batch. (Batch 1 -> Batch 2 -> Batch 3 -> Batch 4)
Now whenever it triggers the last batch, that batch errors out with "first error: [REQUEST_RUNNING_TOO_LONG] Your request was running for too long, and has been stopped."
The above scenario doesn't show up when Batch 1 is triggered manually through anonymous window using Database.executeBatch().
I have tried optimizing the query which had several subqueries. Governor limits are within the threshold limits as well. I have also tried to delete the scheduled job and reschedule it. But nothing seems to work out.
It would be highly appreciated if someone has any additional info on this.

I don't think anyone can answer this without information about what the batch is doing.
